# selecting columns from one data frame by name from a different data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two dataframes:

```
df1<-matrix(data = 1:10,
nrow = 5,
ncol = 5)
colnames(df1)=c("a","b","c","d","e")

df2=c("a","c","e")
```

I want to create a new table using the values from the first data frame but including only the columns whose name is present in the second data frame.

Comment: `df1[, df2]`...

Comment: thanks! that is simpler that what i was trying to do. I had df2 as a dataframe as opposed to a string of characters and it was giving me issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below to your code

```
df3 <- data.frame(df1[,df2])
```